# Python - How to switch frames in a Tkinter window

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I want to switch frames in a Tkinter window but the previous frame always stays visible in the background.

This is the code I have:

```
from tkinter import *

class frame(Frame):

    def __init__(self,display):
        Frame.__init__(self,display)
        l = Label(self,text="frame1")
        l.pack()

class frame2(Frame):

    def __init__(self,display):
        Frame.__init__(self,display)
        l = Label(self,text="frame2")
        l.pack()   

class test(Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        f = frame(self)
        f.grid(row=0)
        f2 = frame2(self)
        f2.grid(row=0)
        f.tkraise()

t = test()
t.mainloop()
```

This works if the layout of the two frames is the same but if I add another label to the second frame, it will still be visible in the Background. Is there a way to switch frames so that only elements from the raised frame are visible?

Comment: Call `.grid()` (or other geometry manager) only on the frame you want to show, and `.grid_remove()` on the other frame(s).  No `.tkraise()` needed.

Comment: Thanks, it works now

Comment: If it's no longer a problem, please consider deleting this question.

Comment: I'm sure there are other people who have the same issue so I'll leave it for everyone to see.

Comment: @BlockCoder, would you add an answer below, in an answer post? That can be marked as solved using the tick device. We welcome self-answers here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As requested, this is what I used to fix my problem:

```
from tkinter import *

class frame(Frame):

    def __init__(self,display):
        Frame.__init__(self,display)
        l = Label(self,text="frame1")
        l.pack()

class frame2(Frame):

    def __init__(self,display):
        Frame.__init__(self,display)
        l = Label(self,text="frame2")
        l.pack()   

class test(Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        f2 = frame2(self)
        f2.grid(row=0)

        #To raise the first frame, I used the following
        frame2.grid_remove()
        f = frame(self)
        f.grid(row=0)

t = test()
t.mainloop()
```